# Unable to pick file (pdf, doc, docx) from download folder in Android 11 and above

Tags: java, android, android-intent, filepicker, realpath

I'm using the [File Picker](https://github.com/jaiselrahman/FilePicker) library.

Permission code:

```java
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.R || Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
                        //Toast.makeText(this, "We can access all files on external storage now", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
                    
                    }
```

Choose file:

```java
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FilePickerActivity.class);
            
                    intent.putExtra(FilePickerActivity.CONFIGS, new Configurations.Builder()
                            .setCheckPermission(true)
                            .setSelectedMediaFiles(mediaFiles)
                            .setShowFiles(true)
                            .setShowImages(false)
                            .setShowAudios(false)
                            .setShowVideos(false)
                            .setIgnoreNoMedia(false)
                            .enableVideoCapture(false)
                            .enableImageCapture(false)
                            .setIgnoreHiddenFile(false)
                            .setMaxSelection(5)
                            .setSuffixes("pdf", "doc", "docx")
                            //.setTitle("Select a file")
                            .build());
                    startActivityForResult(intent, FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

`onActivityResult`:

```java
    if (requestCode == FILE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            //ArrayList<MediaFile> files = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(FilePickerActivity.MEDIA_FILES);
            //Do something with files

            List<MediaFile> mediaFiles = data.<MediaFile>getParcelableArrayListExtra(FilePickerActivity.MEDIA_FILES);
            if (mediaFiles != null) {
                System.out.println(mediaFiles.get(0).getUri());
                setMediaFiles(mediaFiles);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ApplyLeaveActivity.this, "File not selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

Get file from selected location:

```java
    private void setMediaFiles(List<MediaFile> mediaFiles) {
        this.mediaFiles.clear();
        this.mediaFiles.addAll(mediaFiles);
        for (int i = 0; i < mediaFiles.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(mediaFiles.get(i).getUri().getPath());

            /*Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(selectedFile);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", selectedFile);
            }*/

            String path = RealPathUtil.getRealPath(this, mediaFiles.get(i).getUri());
            //String path = getPath(mediaFiles.get(i).getUri());
            if (path != null && !path.isEmpty()) {
                File file = new File(path);

                //String path = getPathFromURI(mediaFiles.get(i).getUri());
                //String path = RealPathUtil.getRealPath(this, mediaFiles.get(i).getUri());
                //System.out.println("Path: " + path);
                ///document/raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/file-sample_150kB(1).pdf
                LeaveDocBean leaveDocBean = new LeaveDocBean();
                leaveDocBean.setId("");
                leaveDocBean.setFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
                //leaveDocBean.setFile(path);
                leaveDocBean.setFileName(path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
                mLeaveDocBeanList.add(leaveDocBean);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to select file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        refreshDocAdapter();
        //fileListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Get its real path:

```java
    public class RealPathUtil {

    public static String getRealPath(Context context, Uri fileUri) {
        String realPath;
        // SDK < API11
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
            realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(context, fileUri);
        }
        // SDK >= 11 && SDK < 19
        else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
            realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(context, fileUri);
        }
        // SDK > 19 (Android 4.4) and up
        else {
            realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API19(context, fileUri);
        }
        return realPath;
    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static String getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        String result = null;

        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(context, contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

        if (cursor != null) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            result = cursor.getString(column_index);
            cursor.close();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static String getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = 0;
        String result = "";
        if (cursor != null) {
            column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            result = cursor.getString(column_index);
            cursor.close();
            return result;
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Get a file path from a Uri. This will get the path for Storage Access
     * Framework Documents, as well as the _data field for the MediaStore and
     * other file-based ContentProviders.
     *
     * @param context The context.
     * @param uri     The Uri to query.
     * @author paulburke
     */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static String getRealPathFromURI_API19(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                /*if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }*/

                // This is for checking Main Memory
                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    if (split.length > 1) {
                        return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                    } else {
                        return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/";
                    }
                    // This is for checking SD Card
                } else {
                    return "storage" + "/" + docId.replace(":", "/");
                }

                // TODO handle non-primary volumes
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(id)) {
                    if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                        return id.replaceFirst("raw:", "");
                    }
                }
                //final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
                //return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);


                String[] contentUriPrefixesToTry = new String[]{
                        "content://downloads/public_downloads",
                        "content://downloads/my_downloads",
                        "content://downloads/all_downloads"
                };
                for (String contentUriPrefix : contentUriPrefixesToTry) {
                    try {
                        final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse(contentUriPrefix), Long.valueOf(id));

                         /*   final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));*/

                        return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        //In Android 8 and Android P the id is not a number
                        return uri.getPath().replaceFirst("^/document/raw:", "").replaceFirst("^raw:", "");
                    }
                }
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("document".equals(type)) {

                    contentUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external", Long.valueOf(split[1]));

                    //   return Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).getPath() + "/" + split[1];
                    //   return  "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/"+split[1];

                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();

            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
     * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
     *
     * @param context       The context.
     * @param uri           The Uri to query.
     * @param selection     (Optional) Filter used in the query.
     * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
     * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
     */
    public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                       String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {
                column
        };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(index);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
     */
    public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }
}
```

Issue: not able to get a file's real path in Android 11 and above; it's working fine up to Android 10. If I choose a file from another location (example: documents, internal storage), it's working in Android 11 and above, but not working if I choose a file from download folders.

Sample path:
Uri: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/document%3A36

ABS Path: /document/document:36 -->not able to get real path

Actual Path: storage/1216-330D/Documents/sample.pdf

Comment: if i select file from download folder, am getting Uri: content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf%3A36. And absolute path: /document/msf:36. here file not found exception and not able to get file name and extension.

Comment: Please note, that content provider can also return files that were deleted from the storage, but was not synced in the content provider's database.

Answer (score 6):

I missed to do this (working fine after adding below code)

```
private String copyFileToInternal(Uri fileUri) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(fileUri, new String[]{OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, OpenableColumns.SIZE}, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
        long size = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE));

        File file = new File(getFilesDir() + "/" + displayName);
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri);
            byte buffers[] = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            while ((read = inputStream.read(buffers)) != -1) {
                fileOutputStream.write(buffers, 0, read);
            }
            inputStream.close();
            fileOutputStream.close();
            return file.getPath();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: All what you do makes no sense. You should use the uri directly and not try to get a path for it. You woukd not need MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE then too.

Comment: okay, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer, download PDF file and save using below path/code and get Uri from the path and share it, it is working fine upto Android 12

```
String dirPath;
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                dirPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).getAbsolutePath() + "/" + getString(R.string.app_name) + "/";
            } else {
                dirPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + getString(R.string.app_name) + "/";
            }
```